# why first program outputs "garbage 300" and second program "0 300" why this is happening?

Tags: c, garbage

In the below code output is "garbage 300" but I am expecting this as "0 300"
why this is happening?

```
    main()
    {
    int a = 300, b, c ;
 if ( a >= 400 )
    b = 300 ;
    c = 200 ;
    printf ( "\n%d %d", b, c ) ;
    }
```

while in below code it is giving expected output as- 0 200

```
main( )
{
int a = 300, b, c ;
   
c = 200 ;
printf ( "\n%d %d", b, c ) ;
}
```

Comment: Because `b` is assigned only in case `a>=400`. And it is not. Proper indentation would help here.

Comment: @Divyank Lalwani Uninitialized variables with automatic storage duration have indeterminate values.

Comment: Why did you change your code in the question? In this one it is clear that you are printing  uninitialized variable (`b`). There is no "second program" as the title is mentioning.

Comment: @EugeneSh I apologize for that,I am new on stack overflow. now I edited that please see it.

Comment: `main()` must return `int` and take arguments `int argc, char** argv`.

Comment: Anyway, your question was addressed in first 3 comments

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. Dupe of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did not understand what you want to say.

Comment: `0` is a perfectly valid garbage value ... as valid as `-8002413217`

Comment: @DivyankLalwani Your programs have undefined behaviors because you are outputting an uninitialized variable with an indeterminate value.

Comment: @DivyankLalwani Uninitialised variables cannot be read, only assigned. Objects in C do not have default values if no initial value is provided. So, `b` and `c` have indeterminate values and cannot be printed until they have been assigned-to. They do _not_ default to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic variables are not automatically initialized. Reading them before writing is undefined behavior. For integers, you usually get some garbage value (whatever happens to be on stack).

Your first program is

```
main()
{
    int a = 300, b, c;
    if (a >= 400)
        b = 300;
    c = 200;
    printf("\n%d %d", b, c) ;
}
```

The condition is wrong, so b does not get assigned a value (it stays uninitialized). That's why you get the garbage.

The second program is essentially the same. `b` happens to have the garbage value `0` in that case.

Automatic variables are all variables defined in a function without storage class specifier `static` or `extern`.

Comment: "_Automatic variables are not automatically initialized._" That's a deliciously ironic way of putting it. I'll have to remember that.